# How can I trigger a content script to run when I click the popup icon of a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Building my first Chrome app and was wondering how to run `myscript.js` only when icon.png is clicked. Now it just runs whenever a page loads.

Here is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name": "My extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background_page": "background.html",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*"],
            "js": ["myscript.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the content script any other time except when the button is pressed, see the Chrome docs on [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#programmatic) to use `executeScript` to inject scripts on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html). Basically the set up is:

- Make another content script that listens for instructions
- When the popup is clicked, fire instructions off to the content script
- Content script does what it needs to do, passes back something that says it's done
- Popup knows the work has been done

This is done so content scripts and background scripts' (or popups) are isolated and secure.